# Are there any libraries that can create a waveform image out of a audio file (mp3)?

Tags: audio, waveform

I want to create a spectrogram out of a audio file.

Are there any libraries that can create a waveform image out of a audio file (mp3) ?

Comment: You keep asking the same question in slightly different forms - try being more specific - what kind of waveform display ? What OS ? What programming language ? Also try reading some of the answers and comments to your previous questions on this same subject.

Comment: I did, but could not find an answer that helped me enough. But I did find a library though. http://www.freesound.org/blog/?p=10

Comment: its for python. is there any other library for iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.freesound.org/blog/?p=10

I found this library, and it works well.